# Static Web App Securing Routes with roles when routes have parameters in them

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-apicontroller, azure-static-web-app, azure-static-website-routing

I have build a react app ( Azure SWA), My API is linked to my web app and I am securing routes with roles (all works well):

```
 {
   "route": "/api/product",
   "allowedRoles": ["admin", "nonadmin"]
 },
 {
   "route": "/api/product/*/delete",
   "allowedRoles": ["admin"]
 },
```

I want only the admin role to be able to call the delete endpoint, but there is a guid that identifies the product and this route does not work when I do this, as wildcards are only supported at ends of routes:

[Microsoft Wildcards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/configuration#wildcards)

Surely there is a way of doing this? as URL parameters are very common, I can seem to find any material on how this is achieved.

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT 13 November 2023**

I've just confirmed with the product group that this is not supported. Wildcard patterns only work at the end of the path.

---

Instead of doing /delete, I would attribute that method with the DELETE verb, that you can do

```json
    {
      "route": "/api/profile*",
      "methods": ["DELETE"],
      "allowedRoles": ["admin"]
    },
```

Besides, using the HTTP verb is more aligned to RESTful principles.

Comment: This is true, but still does not fix the issue, if there is 2 deletes with different role requirements on further routes.

Comment: @Hawkzey I've updated my answer above based off a follow up with the product group. To enable secure routing, you'll need to adjust your RESTful routes for trailing wildcards.

Comment: this still does not fix the problem api/profile* will require all routes past profile to have that role, if there is a route that you want a different role to access this does not work?

Routes should not need to be changed just to cater for this work around :/